# Taking derivative of this equation

Tags: derivatives

$(a+1)^4 \cdot 0.46^a \cdot 0.58^a \cdot 0.71^a \cdot 0.92^a$

I have difficulties with taking the derivative of this function above without using graphic calculator. Someone who knows how to do it?

Comment: Is this derivative with respect to $a$? And have you tried something?

Comment: yes with respect to a. Yes i tried with calculator

Comment: Can you use the fact that $p^x q^x = (pq)^x$ here, where $x$ can be a real number?

Comment: In this site you're not supposed to only show the problem and ask for a solution. You should give some context for the problem, show what you tried and how it failed, in general, give more than just the problem or people will downvote your question. This is not a website to get answers to just post you homework and get answers.

Comment: Have you used the laws of indices to simplify the function? You can put it in the form $(a+1)^4 \times \lambda^a$ for a suitable $\lambda$

Comment: yes i have done it

Comment: then i get 0.17427376^4a * (a+1)^4

Comment: The background question is to find the maximum likelihood estimate for a.

Comment: the function f(x)= (a+1)*x*a   for x1=0.46, x2=0.58, x3=0.71, x4=0.92

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $y = (a+1)^4 \cdot 0.46^a \cdot 0.58^a \cdot 0.71^a \cdot 0.92^a$. You can rewrite this as: $y = (a+1)^4 \cdot 0.17427376
^a$, since $n^a \cdot m^a =(n \cdot m)^a$.

Now, you can use the product rule to evaluate the derivative:

$y' = \left[(a+1)^4 \right]'\cdot 0.17427376
^a +(a+1)^4 \cdot \left[0.17427376
^a \right]'$

Using the chain rule we know that $\left[(a+1)^4 \right]' = 4(a + 1)^3$ and,

$$\begin{align}
\left[0.17427376^a \right]'&=\left[e^{a \ln 0.17427376} \right]'
\\
&=\ln 0.17427376 \cdot e^{a \ln 0.17427376}
\\
&= \ln 0.17427376 \cdot 0.17427376^a 
\end{align}
$$

So you final answer for the derivative is:

$y'= 4(a + 1)^3\cdot 0.17427376
^a +(a+1)^4 \cdot \ln 0.17427376 \cdot 0.17427376^a$

If you wish you can simplify the expression you can write:

$y'= \left(4(a + 1)^3 +(a+1)^4 \cdot \ln 0.17427376 \right)\cdot 0.17427376^a$

This is you derivative

Comment: your calculation is wrong!

Comment: Where am I mistaken?

Comment: i do not no where but the derivative setting equally to zero must give a=1.28947

Comment: The roots of $y'$ are $a = -1$ and $y = 1.28947$, if you compute them with the result  I got for the derivative. @O.N.J.RP

Comment: how did you get that

Comment: I just used Wolfram alpha to compute the zeros for me

Comment: oke sorry for asking again but is there not a easier way to calculate this.

Comment: this calculation is to heavy for the time i have  for this excercise.

Comment: no problem, I'm here to help. There is none I can think of. Just the $(a + 1)^4$ would give you a 4th degree polynomial, and with the exponents I don't see a easy way of solving that

Comment: Is this an exercise where you can use a graphic calculator? @O.N.J.RP

Comment: no im not allowed to use it.

Comment: but also in calculator TI84 do you know a fast way?

Comment: You could plot the function, and find the points where it intersects the x-axis. That's normally the way to go

Comment: Without calculator I don't see how you could solve this. Maybe if you really want to know you can ask another question on this topic

Comment: you mean the derivative, but without having the dervative is that possible?

Comment: I don't think so. How can you calculate the roots of a function if you don't even know the fucion?

Comment: with the dy/dx function on your graphic calculator

Comment: Is my answer for this question good enough?

Comment: yes thank for help!